# Why does VS Setup and Deploy not create these folders on install?

Tags: visual-studio, directory, setup-deployment

I've got a setup and deployment project that I want to create a folder (with two sub folders) in the users MyDocuments directory.
Following what I was able to find, my directory structure looks like this:

[image]

I added the Users Personal Data folder, and created the Trivia Splicer, and sub folders. I also set the folders AlwaysCreate property to true.

When I run this installer on a Windows 8 system, it fails to create these folders which, in turn, causes the program to explode because it expects those directories to be there.
I know that I can (and likely will) just write a simple check that creates the directories if they do not exist, but why is it that the Setup and Deployment installer isn't creating these directories?